# Replace one large word with an entire menu (css/js?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

For this personal sight I'm building I want it to be fairly simple.  I have a big title in the middle of the screen, just one word, and when you hover over it I want it to be replaced with a menu -- basically a white box the size of the title with links on it.

The problem with other solutions I've seen is mostly people want to replace one word with just one word, I could do that.  But I want to change the contents drastically, and I can't quite figure it out.  I'm having trouble getting it to be positioned correctly, as well as there is a LOT of flickering happening.

Confused about how I'd add a whole list of links into the css "content" or js "data" fields.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/186s2crx/1/) of what i'm working with so far as well as my code.

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "main">
        <span class = "maintit"><h1 id = "titre"><em>KIN</em></h1></span>
        <span class = "menu"><p>
            HARRY - CHARLIE - JORDAN
            - JESSICA - RYAN - HANNA -
            SUPERFRUIT - MISC
        </p></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #ED0349;
    font-family:Arial;
    color:#DBFA05;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-size:200px;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px #FFFFFF;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#titre{
    padding-top: .9em;
    background-color: #ED0349;
}

.menu {
    text-align: justify;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.container{
}

.main{
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 50%;
}

.container .menu { display: none; }
.container:hover .maintit {display:none;}
.container:hover .menu {display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the "word" and the menu inside a parent, centered (displayed one on top of  the other.

When the parent is not hovered, display the word and hide the menu.
When the parent is hovered, display the menu and hide the word.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
}
.main > * {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  text-align: center;
  transition: opacity .3s cubic-bezier(.5,0,.3,1);
  position: relative;
}
.main:hover .maintit,.main .menu {
  opacity: 0;
}
.main:hover .menu {
  opacity: 1;
}
body {background-color: gray;}

.main > .menu {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <span class="maintit"><h1 id = "titre"><em>KIN</em></h1></span>
    <span class="menu"><p>
   HARRY - CHARLIE - JORDAN
   - JESSICA - RYAN - HANNA -
   SUPERFRUIT - MISC
  </p></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked great, and there's no more flickering.

Comment: Just one question, what does the ".main > * " selector in the CSS do? Thanks again!

Comment: @Kelly, it selects any immediate child of `.main`.

Comment: thank you! Last question, I want the menu to have a white background and though it's included in my CSS it doesn't happen anymore upon the hover. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I updated my answer with a fix to allow for background color.

Answer (score 1):

The main trouble while hovering is the sizing of `.container`, which is monitored, changes.

Solution: Give `.container` a `height` and `width` and the flickering stops.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ED0349;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #DBFA05;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#titre {
  padding-top: .9em;
  background-color: #ED0349;
}

.menu {
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.main {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 50%;
}

.container .menu {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover .maintit {
  display: none;
}

.container:hover .menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <span class="maintit"><h1 id = "titre"><em>KIN</em></h1></span>
    <span class="menu"><p>
   HARRY - CHARLIE - JORDAN
   - JESSICA - RYAN - HANNA -
   SUPERFRUIT - MISC
  </p></span>
  </div>
</div>
```